# Banach space with subset whose elements are at least $d\gt 0$ far from each other is not separable

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences, separable-spaces

> Let $X$ be a Banach space, and $A\subseteq X$ subgroup, where $A$ is **not** countable, and there is some $d \gt 0$ such that for all $x,y \in A$: $||x-y||>d$. Prove that $X$ is not separable.

My attempt -

Let's assume that $X$ is separable, and let $B$ be the dense countable subset of $X$. Than $A\subseteq \overline B$. Meaning that every element of $A$, is a limit point of some sequence in $B$.

So if I could find a Cauchy sequence in $B$, such that it's limit is in $A$ (that Cauchy sequence has a limit since $X$ is Banach), the property of elements in $A$(that every two elements are at least of distance $d$), would contradict the propeties of Cauchy sequences, and hence $X$ cannot be separable.

Two things that I havn't used are that $B$ is countable and that $A$ is not countable. How can I prove that there is at least one Cauchy sequence in $B$ that converges to some point in $A$?

In fact, how can I know at all that there is Cauchy sequence in $B$?

Or perhaps, is there any other way?

Comment: Any help? I'm really stuck here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is separable iff it contains a dense countable subset. If $A$ if an additive subgroup with points separated more than $d$, then the open sets $(U_a)_{a \in A}$ given by
$$
  U_a = B_a(d/3),
$$
Form an uncountable family of disjoint open sets. Any dense set must intersect each of them, but by disjointedness this would imply that the dense set has uncountable cardinality.

Comment: Nice. So the assumption that $X$ is Banach is not necessary?

Comment: I think this works for general topological spaces. If your space admits an uncountable family of nonempty open sets it can not be separable. No need if metrics or completion.